# ImageMagick adds thick horizontal lines to PNGs extracted from PDF

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick, png

**Edit July 7, 2017:** Downgrading to ImageMagick 6.9.5 solved this problem, which may be Cygwin-specific. I still don't know the underlying cause.

I need to extract data via OCR from images in PDF reports published by Chicago Public Schools. [An example PDF is here (NB: this link downloads the file automatically rather than opening it in the browser).](https://cps.5-essentials.org/2016/s/400009/report/report-climate.pdf) Here's a sample image (from PDF page 11, print page 8), extracted with `pdfimages -png` version `0.52.0` on Cygwin:

[image: Full-sized image]

I'd like to crop each bar into its own file and extract the text with OCR. But when I try this with ImageMagick (version `7.0.4-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-01-25` according to `convert -version`), using the command `convert chart.png -crop 320x600+0+0 bar.png`, I get this image, with horizontal lines that interfere with OCR:

[image: Cropped image with lines]

Running `pdfimages` to extract to PPM format first and then converting to PNG while cropping gives the same result, as does round-trip converting the extracted images to SVG format with ImageMagick's `rsvg` delegate, and fiddling with the PNG alpha channel changes the line's colors from gray to white or black but doesn't eliminate them. I've found a workaround of round-trip converting extracted images through JPG (introducing [ringing artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts), which I hope are irrelevant). But I don't see why I should have to do this. Incidentally, ImageMagick introduces the lines to PNGs even if I run a null conversion `convert chart.png chart.png`, which ought to leave the image unchanged:

[image]

I have found [other complaints that PDF software adds horizontal lines to images](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf%20image%20horizontal%20lines), but none of them exactly matches this problem. A discussion thread mentions that [versions of the PDF standard somehow differ in their treatment of alpha channels](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=30755), but my knowledge of graphics is too poor understand the discussion fully; besides, my images get horizontal lines added after they're extracted from the PDF, because of something internal to ImageMagick. Can anyone shed some light on the causes of the grey lines?

Comment: The preferred command for V7 starts with magick - convert is being depreciated but can still work depending on the setup. Some people have had different results between using convert and magick so give magick a go. I would also try a different pdf in case the pdf file is the problem.

Comment: Null conversions with `magick` rather than `convert` give the same results, as do graphs from different PDF files. (The PDF images that aren't bar graphs don't get added lines, but they're also useless to me.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest ImageMagick 7.0.6.0 Q16 Mac OS X, I get a good result. As mentioned above by Bonzo, the correct syntax for IM 7 is magick rather than convert. The use of convert reverts to IM 6. Also do not use magick convert either.

```
magick chart.png -crop 320x600+0+0 +repage bar.png
```

[image]

If this does not work for you, then there must have been a bug in your older version of IM 7. So you should then upgrade.

Note also the +repage is needed to remove the virtual canvas